# Is this a safe way to empty a list in Golang?

Tags: list, go

An traditional way:

```
// Clear all elements by iterating
var next *Element
for e := l.Front(); e != nil; e = next {
    next = e.Next()
    l.Remove(e)
}
```

How about using:

```
l.Init()
```

Is it a safe way that will not causing any memory leak?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From http://golang.org/pkg/container/list/#List.Init

> > Init initializes **or clears list l**.

A side note, a slice is probably better for most usage scenarios, check [Slice Tricks](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/SliceTricks).

Comment: And if you use a slice, `s = s[:0]` resets its length to `0`, which is often close enough to clearing it (but is not an official Slice Trick yet, alas :) ).

Comment: @twotwotwo does it keep a reference to underlying array so if you have b = make(int[], 100) and a = b[:0] even when b is garbage collected a internally will still maintain a reference to that big ass array?

Comment: @matt your question is awesome, you need to ask it as a separate question. I had to test it out and yep it keeps the underlying array! [proof!](http://play.golang.org/).

Comment: Yep. In exchange for keeping the old array around, `append()`s won't allocate a new array until you exceed its old capacity ([see spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types) if those terms don't make sense). Also: almost sure that if items in a contain pointers, none of the items they point to can be GC'd, because they'd be reachable again if you re-lengthened the slice with `a = a[:cap(a)]`. So if your items contain pointers (or are pointers), zero/nil them out after `a = a[:0]` if you want the pointed-to objects GC'd.